# PHP7 atomic caching for read with arrays

Tags: php, caching, php-7, apc, clickhouse

I'm in need of some caching since the database isn't able to sustain a huge amount of writes without batch queries. Therefore I need to cache queries to run them in batch once a second.

Now since the only way to achieve this with PHP is to use some caching system, I thought about apcu, since it is using shared memory which is probably the fastest for this need of one cache entry per request (requests are in the thousands per second).

My main issue is finding a way of implementation that is atomic.

I thought about caching everything under the current datetime (each datetime would contain a few thousand records), then using the iterator to select and delete everything < current date time. But the read/delete wouldn't be atomic and there is no option to push to an array and reading -> modifying -> writing ain't atomic.

Do you have any tips on how I could achieve this or is there no luck with PHP?

Comment: Caching seems a very bad solution for this, perhaps if you shared your database structure, it may be easier to suggest how to fix the existing problem

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way around using batch queries, the database (clickhouse) wasn't designed for small inserts.

Comment: I've added Clickhouse as a tag to your question, these sorts of details are important when trying to get help.

Comment: Could you have a separate database (MySQL  for example) to act as a cache?

Comment: Adding another database adds a point of failure and mysql is incredible troublesome since it doesn't scale linear. If at all it would need something like cassandra or redis but I would like to avoid that, btw. at this point I could probably write to a file on a mem disk and have less performance impact. I would probably prefer using a different language over adding another service to the stack.

Comment: Sounds like you want both scalable as well as durable, this would most likely need another service as if your php server crashes, you would loose any cache on that server (this would be the case of any non replicated data).  Also caches don't guarantee data storage, they just act as a faster way of getting it.

Comment: That is exactly why I would like to use shared memory, because it is way faster than any third party application can deliver. Especially since PHP can't share a stream between requests. I would write once per second, if there is a crash during this time, this < one second is the smallest issue.

Comment: And if that server dies  - your happy to lose the data.

Comment: What do you think happens when mysql crashes? That won't be one second loss of data ;) Even if it is a cluster, there is probably a 50ms delay at least that would be lost. MySQL nodes are probably way less stable than PHP with APCu, too.

Comment: Totally forgot to mention, what happens if the server crashes that moves data from mysql to clickhouse? In order for it to be atomic it requires a transaction, therefor it is deleted before written to clickhouse.

Comment: My example of MySQL was just an example.  You could use redis, RabbitMQ, etc....  Also if your that worried about the data - IMHO PHP isn't the best solution.

Comment: At some point I'll probably port it to go, but for now it is in PHP. Does this mean there is absolutely no way to use the apc cache atomic? I really do not want to add another point of failure.

Comment: I'm probably going with a socket solution between PHP and golang and letting golang handle all the caching and batch inserting.